# Unable to set cursor position in content editable div - Jquery

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

Heres a jquery code, to set the cursor position in content editable div to position `10`

```
var range,selection; var contentEditableElement = $("div#editMe");
if(document.createRange)//Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE 9+
{
 range = document.createRange();
 range.selectNodeContents(contentEditableElement);
 range.collapse(true);
 range.setStart(contentEditableElement,0); 
 range.setEnd(contentEditableElement,10);
 selection = window.getSelection();
 selection.removeAllRanges();
 selection.addRange(range);
}
```

But this ones not working. Whats the problem . ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example. It doesnt seems to work if I only put text inside the div, I have to put every single character each in an element. Also notice that you have to use .get(0) on a jquery object to actually get a dom object to use with range.setStart and range.setEnd.

html:

```
<div id="editMe">
    <span>a</span><span>b</span><span>c</span><span>d</span><span>e</span><span>f</span><span>g</span><span>h</span><span>i</span><span>j</span><span>k</span><span>l</span><span>m</span><span>n</span>
</div>

<button onclick="do_select()">
    select characters
</button>
```

js:

```
function do_select()
{
    var element = $("div#editMe").get(0);
    var range = document.createRange();

    range.collapse(true);
    range.setStart(element,0); 
    range.setEnd(element,10);

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8pWs/